# Continue test after expect exception phpunit

Tags: php, exception, transactions, phpunit

i have code.

```
        try {
            $this->entityManager->beginTransaction();

            $this->repo->remove($something);
            $this->repoTwo->delete($something);

            $this->entityManager->commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->entityManager->rollback();

            throw new Exception($e->getMessage(), 0, $e);
        }
```

And now, i want to test, if there is still record in database, after exception, how i can do that, if test wont work after exception is expected?

```
    $this->expectException(Exception::class);
    $this->expectExceptionMessage('xxxx');

    app(Command::class)->handle();

    $this->seeInDatabase($table, [
        'id' => $media->id(),
    ]);
```

How i can do that? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to check this. You class should have all the dependencies mocked, so you can just check that `rollback` was called.

Comment: @freeek But, if i try mock entityManager and try to check if rollback is called, anyway i should do that, after i call my function, but after `pp(MediaCleanupCommand::class)->handle();` nothing works (also die();),

Comment: Yes, but you should mock before `handle()`, so this will be fine. No code after is needed.

Comment: @freeek Thanks, work like this, are there no chance, that i can test, that record on database actually are there?

Comment: From my point of view unit testing doesn't require this. If you'd test it end-to-end, that would make sense. You check that your method performs as designed: so transaction is rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you might create two tests. One that tests an exception was thrown and one that [depends](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.3/annotations.html#depends) on the first test and tests the record still exists, but in this case the database would be reset before each test, including test dependencies so it won't work as you might expect.

But you can still do two tests and have one depend on the other, however you need to re-run the same code in both test (because the database would be reset in between the tests). The "depends" in this case is merely documenting that one test is associated with the other.

```php
public function testOne()
{
    $this->expectException(Exception::class);
    $this->expectExceptionMessage('xxxx');

    app(Command::class)->handle();
}

/**
 * @depends testOne
 */
public function testTwo($arg)
{
    app(Command::class)->handle();

    $this->seeInDatabase($table, [
        'id' => $media->id(),
    ]);
}
```

If you really want to end-to-end test it, and do the assertions in the same test, then you can use a `try ... catch` block and test it procedurally.

```php
public function testException()
{
    try {
        app(Command::class)->handle();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Make sure you catch the specific exception that you expect to be
        // thrown, (e.g. the exception you would normally specify in the
        // expectException method: $this->expectException(Exception::class);

        // Assert the exception message.
        $this->assertEquals('xxxx', $e->getMessage());

        // Assert database still contains record.
        $this->seeInDatabase($table, [
            'id' => $media->id(),
        ]);

        return;
    }

    // If the expected exception above was not caught then fail the test.
    $this->fail('optional failure message');
}
```